# Long table cells adjustment

Tags: longtable, cell

well I'm facing a problem using `longtable` in latex. My problem is that I could not adjust my `longtable` cells correctly.  Below my `longtable` example :

```
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{seqsplit}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage[title]{appendix}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\theenumii}
\renewcommand{\theenumii}{\theenumi.\arabic{enumii}.}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}}
\newcommand\tab[1][1.25cm]{\hspace*{#1}}

\usepackage{chngcntr}

\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
\counterwithout{table}{chapter}

\usepackage{titletoc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/titletoc
\titlecontents*{chapter}% <section-type>
  [0pt]% <left>
  {}% <above-code>
  {\bfseries\chaptername\ \thecontentslabel\quad}% <numbered-entry-format>
  {}% <numberless-entry-format>
  {\bfseries\hfill\contentspage}% <filler-page-format>

 \let\origaddvspace\addvspace
 \renewcommand{\addvspace}[1]{}

\addto{\captionsfrench}{% Making babel aware of special titles
  \renewcommand{\mtctitle}{Plan}
}


\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\newpage
\begin{longtable}{|p{0.05\linewidth}|p{0.1\linewidth}|p{0.25\linewidth}|p{0.45\linewidth}|}
  \hline 
 \centering &\centering Test & \centering  Description & \centering  Service
   \tabularnewline
 \endhead
  \hline
  1&testFoundingAllCertificateWithPrivateKey & &CertificateService.extractAllCertificates() \\
  \hline
  2& testRetrieveCertificateWithNonInitializedKeyStore & & CertificateService.extractAllCertificates()\\
  \hline
    3& & &CertificateService.signDataCMS() \\
  \hline
    4& & &CertificateService.signDataCMS() \\
  \hline
    5& & &CertificateService.signDataCMS() \\
  \hline
    6& & &CertificateService.signDataCMS() \\
  \hline
    7& & &CertificateService.signDataCMS() \\
  \hline
  \caption{Les tests unitaires}
  \end{longtable} 

\end{document}
```

the output is like this :[image]

is there any method that adjust the text automatically ?

Comment: it's not really related to longtable you just have `\parbox{0.05\linewidth}{testFoundingAllCertificateWithPrivateKey }`  with a long unbreakable word in a very narrow column.  perhaps `test\-Founding\-All\-Certificate\-With\-Private\-Key ` or perhaps you want to allow breaks with no hyphen or allow breaks at any letter. Or perhaps you can allow that column to be wider...You need to decide

Comment: or it may be better to change the layout with test name on one line as a heading and the rest as a normal paragraph below it (that is set it as a description list not a table)

Comment: thank you for your quick response, i want to allow breaks at any letter, because i can't allow that column to be wider. Can you tell me how to let it breaks at any letter ?

Comment: there is an answer on site about that, I'll see what I can find.

Comment: that's what the seqsplit package (which you are loading but not using) is for.  https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=seqsplit   By the way your example document can not be run as posted.